# How would you go about using react-router to facilitate a large amount of sub routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am creating a web app using the MERN stack to manage school assignments. With the nature of this app, I have to create a ton of routes because I am assigning every assignment to its own url. Example: `webapp.com/assignments/0001`, `webapp.com/assignments/0002` etc. I realize you could probably route these manually by using `<Route exact path to="/assignments/0001" component={example}/>`. However, I am convinced there is a more effecient way to do this. I am really new to programming in general, so if this is a dumb question, sorry. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Take a look at react-router-dom's nesting documentation/example: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Answer (score 1):

Through "configuration":

```js
const routes = {
 '001': componentFor001,
 '002': componentFor002,
 '003': componentFor003
 ...
}
```

In your component, something like this:

```
return (
  <Switch>
   {Object.entries(routes).map(([path,component]) => 
      <Route exact path={`/assignments/${path}`} component={component}/>
   )}
  </Switch>
)
```